# Disable one Zend Multioption form MultiCheckbox

Tags: php, checkbox, zend-framework, zf1

I am creating a multicheckbox and filling it afterwards with a loop. Is it possible to disable one of the checkboxes afterwards or during the filling?

```
$multiOptions = array();
$multiCheckbox = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('multi_name', $multiOptions);
foreach($valuesArray AS $value) {
    $name = $this->getName($value);
    $multiCheckbox->addMultiOption($name, $value);
}
```

I tryed to disable one checkbox by code below, but it did not work. Anyone got better suggestions?

```
$multiCheckbox->setAttrib('disable', $this->getName($valuesArray[2]));
```

this did not help either:

```
$multiCheckbox->setAttrib('disable', $valuesArray[2]);
```

The array with values is just a simple array:

```
$valuesArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: I am thinking you will need a custom decorator to achieve this.

Comment: It should be $multiCheckbox->setAttrib('disable', $this->getName($valuesArray[2]));

Comment: @Rijndael, tried that before, did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create a new view helper to so that you can set the disabled attribute of the element when it is displayed.

The current view helper code looks like this:

```
public function formMultiCheckbox($name, $value=null, $attribs=null, $options=null, $listsep="<br />\n") {
    return $this->formRadio($name, $value, $attribs, $options, $listsep);
}
```

You should be able to set an 'disabledElement' option when you are creating your multicheckbox and then in your view helper check if the checkbox being displayed should be disabled or not.

```
public function formMultiCheckbox($name, $value=null, $attribs=null, $options=null, $listsep="<br />\n") {
    $disableElements = $options['disableElement']; 

    if(in_array($name, $disableElements, true)) {
        $options['disable'] => true;
    }

    return $this->formRadion($name, $value, $attribs, $options, $listsep);
}
```

Overriding the view helper to check which elements should be disabled and then setting the option should work.

You may want to extend the `Form_Element_MultiCheckbox` into your own class and creating the view helper for that element yourself. [Based on the Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom)

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do, but it does not solve my problem. As I see it, you are tying to disable the whole Form_Element_MultiCheckbox(contains many checkboxes)? I want to disable just one MultiOption(one particular checkbox).

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  That is what you are doing in the view helper.  Zend is looping through all the checkbox elements and creating them.  So you override the function and add a check to add a disabled option to the one that you want disabled.

Comment: Since I am not using the view, but instead constructing a custom JSON that is later rendered using a template engine I never reach the view helper. So to solve my problem I changed the template and rendering algorithm to include new option... But I suppose if one would use the view, your(@Schleis) solution is the correct one.

Comment: The question is not answered here.